# Defining function to convert word to lowercase

Tags: python

Newbie question:

Is there a way to do the following below with out defining an input?

```
def lowercase():
x = input('Enter Text:')
print('lowercase:',x.lower())
lowercase()"
```

I just need to pass in an ARG and have it print out the ARG.

Example:

lowercase: arg

I tried the following below, but I get the following error: NameError: name 'ARG' is not defined.

```
def lowercase(x):
print("lowercase:", x.lower())
lowercase(ARG)
```

Comment: There is a severe issue with your first code example. Please fix this.

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you claim. It raises an `IndentationError`. If you fix that, it raises a `SyntaxError` because of the stay `"` character. If you're explicitly asking newbie questions, you can't ask us to assume that you know better in your real code; give us exactly the code. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance.

Comment: Meanwhile, what do you mean by "pass in an ARG"? You want to pass in a command-line argument? You have some variable that you want to pass in? You want to call input and pass that in? Or did you just die while carving the code, like the Castle of Aaargh?

Answer (score 2):

Pass a string:

```
def lowercase(a):
    print('lowercase:',a.lower())
lowercase("FOO")
```

Or define a variable `ARG`:

```
ARG = "FOO"

def lowercase(a):
    print('lowercase:',a.lower())
lowercase(ARG)
```

Unless you have a variable `ARG` defined somewhere that is a `string`, you cannot call the `str.lower()` method on it.

So either pass a string directly as in the first example or you must have a variable defined that points to a `string` if you want to pass a variable

On a side note, use `lowercase` when naming variables.

Comment: If `lowercase` calls `print` (and returns `None`), you don't need to  use `print` when you call the function.

Comment: @chepner, yep fixed. Too used to using pycharm